# Call to undefined function _() after deploying to server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel

I have a Laravel app that I've been working on. while it works just fine on my local environment when I upload it to my college's server and try to run it I get this error:

`Call to undefined function _() (View: /home/user/public_html/MeetHub/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)`

```
/home/user/public_html/MeetHub/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php
     * @param  array   $__data
     * @return string
     */
    protected function evaluatePath($__path, $__data)
    {
        $obLevel = ob_get_level();

        ob_start();

        extract($__data, EXTR_SKIP);

        // We'll evaluate the contents of the view inside a try/catch block so we can
        // flush out any stray output that might get out before an error occurs or
        // an exception is thrown. This prevents any partial views from leaking.
        try {
            include $__path;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $this->handleViewException(new FatalThrowableError($e), $obLevel);
        }

        return ltrim(ob_get_clean());
    }

    /**
     * Handle a view exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @param  int  $obLevel
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function handleViewException(Exception $e, $obLevel)
```

edit:
Tried `composer update` and  `composer dump`

edit2: Now both server and local environments have the same php version. Same error.

Comment: Might after uploading, your address is different, could you run composer update in your server?

Comment: triend both composer update and dump. Same error.

Comment: Sorry about old comment, what is your php version in your server?

Comment: On my server it's 7.1.32 and
on my local environment its 7.3.6.
Could this be it?

Comment: _() is a PHP shortcut for a function called gettext, which is used in translation. To resolve this, check the documentation for ampps, and make sure you have gettext installed into PHP. Good luck, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: From what I can see gettext exists in PHP versions 5.4 and up so it should be in both environments. I also ran ```composer require gettext/gettext```. Same error.

Comment: What is your Laravel version?

Comment: My Laravel version is 5.8.35